# How to adapt Get-ChildItemToDepth to return Depth in array ?

Tags: arrays, powershell

I using PowerShell 2.0 and using a function to list all directory ending by "_S" on 2 level depth 
Example where Push-Location = "\\MyServer\Shared\toto\" the result is:

```
\\MyServer\Shared\toto\Folder1_S
\\MyServer\Shared\toto\Folder1_S\Folder2_S 
\\MyServer\Shared\toto\Folder1_S\Folder3_S
```

Now, i would like this function return level depth number in array
For example i would like this result

```
1; \\MyServer\Shared\toto\Folder1_S
2;\\MyServer\Shared\toto\Folder1_S\Folder2_S 
2; \\MyServer\Shared\toto\Folder1_S\Folder3_S
```

.

```
function Get-ChildItemToDepth {
  param(
    [String]$Path = $PWD,
    [String]$Filter = "*_S",
    [Byte]$ToDepth = 2,
    [Byte]$CurrentDepth = 0,
    [Switch]$DebugMode
  )

  $CurrentDepth++
  if ($DebugMode) { $DebugPreference = "Continue" }


    Get-ChildItem $Path | ForEach-Object {$_ | Where-Object { ($_.Attributes -match "Directory") -and ($_.Name -like $Filter) } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
    #Write-Host $CurrentDepth

    if ($_.PsIsContainer) {
      if ($CurrentDepth -le $ToDepth) {
        # Callback to this function
        Get-ChildItemToDepth -Path $_.FullName -Filter $Filter -ToDepth $ToDepth -CurrentDepth $CurrentDepth
      } else {
        Write-Host $("Skipping GCI for Folder: $($_.FullName) " +
          "(Why: Current depth $CurrentDepth vs limit depth $ToDepth)")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How to adpat the funtion to return an array with depth ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of outputing the `FullName`-value, create a string with your current depth and fullname. Ex (I've also cleaned it up a bit):

```
function Get-ChildItemToDepth {
  param(
    [String]$Path = $PWD,
    [String]$Filter = "*_S",
    [int]$MaxDepth = 2,
    [int]$CurrentDepth = 1,
    [Switch]$DebugMode
  )

  if ($DebugMode) { $DebugPreference = "Continue" }

    Get-ChildItem $Path | Where-Object { $_.PSIsContainer } | ForEach-Object {
        #Write-Host $CurrentDepth

        if ($_.Name -like $Filter) {
            #Match found. Output "Level; Path"
            "$CurrentDepth; $($_.FullName)"
        }

        #Recursion
        if ($CurrentDepth -lt $MaxDepth) {
            # Callback to this function
            Get-ChildItemToDepth -Path $_.FullName -Filter $Filter -MaxDepth $MaxDepth -CurrentDepth ($CurrentDepth + 1)
        } else {
            Write-Host $("Skipping GCI for Folder: $($_.FullName) " +
            "(Why: Current depth $CurrentDepth vs limit depth $MaxDepth)")
        }
    }
}

Get-ChildItemToDepth -Path \\MyServer\Shared\toto\
```